# Can i make react js Website with Flutter app

Tags: reactjs, flutter, api, rest

I'm  thinking about creating a website with React js as front-end, and later think about back-end, but I want to create an application for the website with Flutter
Does a Flutter application work with and take API and data from a Reactjs website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better read and search more.
However, You will need to use the same APIs that this React App is using, then it won't matter if you are using ReactJS or Flutter into creating this web app (Since flutter supports creating web apps too).